# How can I draw text at any angle above and parallel to a line?

Tags: python, tkinter, geometry, tkinter-canvas

I want to place a text centrally above the line (controlled with variable `distance`). There is a method `drawLineDescription()` for this. This method takes the start and endpoints of the lines and then calculates the center point `x, y`. I have already worked with `angle` to ensure that the text is placed correctly. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to place the text vertically over the line at every angle, i.e. depending on the rotation the variables `x, y` have to be able to move. How can I supplement this?

```
def drawLineDescription(canvas, startX, startY, endX, endY, distance):
        lengthX = endX - startX
        lengthY = endY - startY
        x = int(startX+((lengthX)/2))
        y = int(startY+((lengthY)/2))

        angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(lengthY, lengthX)*-1)
        angle = round(angle)
        if angle < -90 or angle > 90:
           angle += 180

        canvas.create_text(x, y, angle=angle, font=("Arial", 12), text="exampleText")
```

In the end it should look like this (example of multiple lines with text - the lines never cross their text):
[Example result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBf6h.png)

Comment: What is real problem - calculate central point of the text at needed distance? Or find starting (left) point (so you need text width)?

Comment: @MBo I want to calculate the central point of the text at needed distance. To calculate the text width I have already written a function ;-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
lengthX = endX - startX
lengthY = endY - startY
fullLength = math.sqrt(lengthX**2 + lengthY**2)
#unit direction vector
ux = lengthX / fullLength
uy = lengthY / fullLength
#unit normal
if ux < 0:
    nx, ny = -uy, ux
else:
    nx, ny = uy, -ux
#text center point (D at the picture)
cx = x + nx * distance
cy = y + ny * distance

#if you need start of text (S at the picture)
sx = x + nx * distance - ux * halfwidth
sy = y + ny * distance - uy * halfwidth
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer - this is very close to the goal. Unfortunately the solution is not quite perfect. The text sometimes crosses the line or the text is displayed upside down. Look at the demonstration of your code here:[watch video demo](https://1drv.ms/v/s!Ahvfc1_FY97C4AE8odX4YZyfaBxW?e=fkepl0) Notice that the text is "999" and sometimes it displays "666" -  I would be very happy if you could update your answer

Comment: Yes, mistake was in `else` branch

Answer (score 1):

You can draw rotated text on tkinter if you are using `tcl > 8.6` with the following instructions: `canvas_item = tk.create_text`, and `canvas.itemconfig(canvas_item, angle=rotation_angle)`

In order to achieve what you want, you need a little bit of geometry, notably the coordinates of the line segment, its mid point, an offset vector perpendicular to the segment, and the angle of the segment.

I encapsulated the arithmetic necessary to calculate the proper geometric elements in a class `point`, and in c class `Vector`. These classes are not bullet proof, but they give you a starting point for basic geometry.

I added an example of a line defined by two points, with the text placed as you need and rotated to match the direction of the line segment.

[image]

```
import math
import tkinter as tk


class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self, other: 'Vector'):
        return Vector(other.x + self.x, other.y + self.y)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Vector(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y)

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.x
        yield self.y

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({self.x}, {self.y})'


class Vector:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Point(other.x + self.x, other.y + self.y)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Vector(other.x - self.x, other.y - self.y)

    def scale(self, scalar):
        return Vector(self.x * scalar, self.y * scalar)

    def normal(self):
        norm = self.norm()
        return Vector(self.x / norm, self.y / norm)

    def norm(self):
        return math.hypot(self.x, self.y)

    def perp(self):
        x, y = self.normal()
        return Vector(y, -x)

    def angle(self):
        return math.atan2(-self.y, self.x) * (180 / math.pi)

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.x
        yield self.y

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({self.x}, {self.y})'


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)

    p0, p1 = Point(100, 40), Point(200, 300)
    segment = p1 - p0
    mid_point = segment.scale(0.5) + p0
    # canvas.create_oval(*(mid_point - Vector(2, 2)), *(Vector(2, 2) + mid_point))

    line = canvas.create_line(*p0, *p1)
    offset = segment.perp().scale(20)
    # canvas.create_line(*mid_point, *(mid_point+offset))

    txt = canvas.create_text(*(offset + mid_point), text='example')
    canvas.itemconfig(txt, angle=segment.angle())

    canvas.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Good solution for an object-oriented approach, which certainly has its justification.